# haskellでの絶対値の定義

Tags: haskell

Haskellで絶対値を定義したいのですが、いまいち定義の仕方がよくわかりませんでした。
ちなみに、自分は以下のように定義したのですがどこがおかしいでしょうか。

```
abs(x)=if x<0 then -x
  else if 0<=x then x
```

（絶対値の関数はabsとさせてもらいました。）

Answer (score 3):

示された定義右辺にある2つめのif式にelse節がないので，文法エラーになります．
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
(このエラーメッセージがちょっと判りにくいですね)
通常の数値に対する絶対値関数を定義するなら，if式は2段にする必要はなく

```
abs x = if x < 0 then -x else x
```

でよいかと思います．さて，文法的にはこれでパスしますが，使おうとすると．

```
*Main> abs (-3)

Ambiguous occurence `abs'
...
```

のようなエラーになります．これは，数値型（型クラスNumのインスタンスの型）に対する絶対値関数 abs はデフォルトでインポートされる標準 Prelude モジュールで定義済みで，どちらを使ってよいか判らないという趣旨のエラーメッセージです．当初の目的が，絶対値関数を使いたいということであれば，定義済みのものを使えばよいし，独自に定義した絶対値関数を使いたいのであれば，関数名が被らないようにする必要があります．